# Android Custom list adapter- Color for each list entry

Tags: android, listadapter, android-sensors, custom-lists

I have a list of Android sensors in the UI. My whole application is a service and each sensor can be turned on/off by sending HTTP Post requests. Example, http ://IPaddress:port/accelerometer/on will turn on the accelerometer. My requirement is to change the color of the list entry to RED when the sensor is switched on and turn it to BLACK when the sensor is switched off. Multiple sensors can be turned on simultaneously.  I use the below code, but please let me know how can I change multiple sensor entries in the list? i.e, if 3 sensors are turned on, all the color of the entries in the list should  change to RED. Thanks in advance!

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
View rowView = convertView;
TextViewHolder holder = null;   
if(rowView == null)
{   
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
holder = new TextViewHolder(); 
holder.txt = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
rowView.setTag(holder);  
}
else{       
    holder = (TextViewHolder) rowView.getTag();     
}
if(values[position].contains(sensor) && state[position])
{
((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setText(values[position]);  
}  
else if(values[position].contains(sensor) && (!state[position]))
   {  ((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     ((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setText(values[position]);
}
else
{       
holder.txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
holder.txt.setText(values[position]);    
}  
return rowView;
}
```

UPDATE: I have 17 sensors in my list. But there are 2 sensors for gravity, linear acceleration etc. The getView() method iterates only for the first 10 entries and repeats those.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this:

```
if(position %2 ==0){
((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
else{
((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: The list should change color dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing again your text view to set text and setting the color of another instance

you have to use the same instance of text view to set text and set color

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
View rowView = convertView;
TextViewHolder holder = null;   
if(rowView == null)
{   
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
holder = new TextViewHolder(); 
holder.txt = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
rowView.setTag(holder);  
}
else{       
    holder = (TextViewHolder) rowView.getTag();     
}
if(values[position].contains(sensor) && state[position])
{
holder.txt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
holder.txt.setText(values[position]);  
}  
else if(values[position].contains(sensor) && (!state[position]))
   {  holder.txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     holder.txt.setText(values[position]);
}
else
{       
holder.txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
holder.txt.setText(values[position]);    
}  
   return rowView;
    }
```

try this code it is edited hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can create different drawables and shapes and in your custom adapter you chose the right one:
For example:
Rounded corner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
<solid android:color="#00FF00"/>
<corners android:radius="5dp" />    
<padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" />
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#00CC00"/>
```

and then

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

and finally in your custom adapter:

```
 v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.planetNameView = tv;
    v.setTag(holder);
    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
```

Of course in your case you select the right backgorund depending on the position for example.
If you want to have more info give a look at my blog [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-listview-background-row-style.html)